# ios - How to load data from JSON url in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uitableview

I'm new to iPhone development,I'm trying to bind data from `JSON` Url in `UITableview`, but I'm getting an error in the below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://80f237c226fa45aaa09a5f5c82339d46.cloudapp.net/DownloadService.svc/Courses"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
[self.dropdownTblView reloadData];
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) 
{
    _altTitle = [status valueForKey:@"Title"];
    NSLog(@"Title %@",_altTitle);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSLog(@"%d",[statuses count]);
   return [statuses count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
return cell;

 //Here I'm getting an error    
id obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [obj valueForKey:@"Title"];
cell.textLabel.text =name;
return cell;
}
```

This is my JSON

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Tamil to English",
    "AltTitle": "‡Æ§|‡ÆÆ‡Æø|‡Æ¥‡Øç| |‡ÆÆ‡ØÇ|‡Æ≤|‡ÆÆ‡Øç| |‡ÆÜ|‡Æô‡Øç|‡Æï‡Æø|‡Æ≤|‡ÆÆ‡Øç",
    "Description": "Learn English through Tamil",
    "Code": 1,
    "Version": "1.0",
    "SourceLanguageIndicator": "‡ÆÖ",
    "TargetLanguageIndicator": "A",
    "SourceLanguageCode": "ta",
    "TargetLanguageCode": "en",
    "Updated": "2013-02-21T03:33:19.6601651+00:00"
  }    
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: so? what is the error?

Comment: You're returning the cell twice in the same scope, try to delete the first `return cell;`

Comment: Check what statuses is returning?I mean once you get parsed data just print and check whether it is dictionary or array.And remove first return cell statement.

Comment: Could you please tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: I'm assigning statuses as NSArray

Comment: [__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e93270 2013-05-31 14:27:31.639 VerboGym[1985:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e93270 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Did you had a chance to try my answer, i tested here and its working fine for me.

Comment: I'm assigning like this,it's working

NSArray *array =[[statuses valueForKey:@"Title"]allObjects];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:0]; 

Thanks to all.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the cell twice in the same scope, try to delete the first `return cell;`, also you're calling `reloadData` on the table just before the `for` loop; in this case probably the dataSource of the table is still empty, so call `reloadData` just after the `for` loop.

EDIT:
It's strange what is happening, the `objectFromString` [must return](http://superloopy.io/json-framework/api/3.0/interfaceSBJsonParser.html#a1ec40b986576044d58d30172b141c74c) a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary` but it seems that is pointing to an `NSSet`. I can suggest 2 things in addition:

1. It seems that you're not usig ARC since you're calling `autorelease` on the `UITableViewCell`. In this case you're leaking `parser` and `json_string` in the `viewDidLoad`, so `release` them.
2. **Make sure** to call `[super viewDidLoad];` (you're not doing this in your code).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,but still I'm getting an error

Comment: @user2439531 What's your error? Also, i don't understand if you're using ARC or not.

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: Have you put the `[self.dropdownTblView reloadData];` after the for loop as stated in my response? Maybe set a breakpoint to check which line is raising the error.

Comment: Exactly here id obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: [__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e93270
2013-05-31 14:27:31.639 VerboGym[1985:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e93270 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Well, really strange, it seems that your statuses is not an array but a set. Does you first NSLog is printing out the title?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you set the type of `obj` as `id`. It is too generic and may not know how to respond to `valueForKey`. Have you tried declaring `obj` as an `NSDictionary *` instead? Like the code below:

```
NSDictionary *obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [obj valueForKey:@"Title"];
```

Comment: I think that's not the problem. Since he knows that there is a dictionary, it's ok to set it as id.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below code in your `ViewDidload` and  Run the Project , it will work.

> Note :You're returning the cell twice, try to delete the first return
>   cell;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    statuses=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://80f237c226fa45aaa09a5f5c82339d46.cloudapp.net/DownloadService.svc/Courses"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                              id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];


                                NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@",jsonObject);

                               statuses=[jsonObject mutableCopy];

                               [self.coursetable reloadData];
                           }];

    NSLog(@"myURL=%@",myURL);

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[statuses count]);
    return [statuses count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    id obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[obj valueForKey:@"Title"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I'm using Xcode 3.2 so NSJSONSerialialization not supported

Comment: Okay , then Just use the rest ,

Just use as below

**Nsarray *myarray = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
statuses=[myarray mutableCopy]; Then reload the Tableview.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {

  NSString *dictStr=@"{\"Id\": 1,\"Title\": \"Tamil to English\",\"AltTitle\": \"‡Æ§|‡ÆÆ‡Æø|‡Æ¥‡Øç| |‡ÆÆ‡ØÇ|‡Æ≤|‡ÆÆ‡Øç| |‡ÆÜ|‡Æô‡Øç|‡Æï‡Æø|‡Æ≤|‡ÆÆ‡Øç\",\"Description\": \"Learn English through Tamil\",\"Code\": 1,\"Version\": \"1.0\",\"SourceLanguageIndicator\": \"‡ÆÖ\",\"TargetLanguageIndicator\": \"A\",\"SourceLanguageCode\": \"ta\",\"TargetLanguageCode\": \"en\",\"Updated\": \"2013-02-21T03:33:19.6601651+00:00\"}";

 NSDictionary *rootDict =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [dictStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error: nil];
     NSArray *keys=[[rootDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
   }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
     return [keys count];
   }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
     UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if (cell==nil) {
      cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }

      cell.textLabel.text=[rootDict valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      return cell;
  }
```

**remember rootDict and keys will be declared as global.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was thinking right, statuses is not NSArray, it is NSSet so if you call objectAtIndex on NSSet it will crash.To get array convert NSSet into NSArray.

```
NSArray *array =[statuses allObjects];
```

Comment: Probably yes, but i'm wondering why `objectFromString` is returning a set instead of an array? The docs of `objectFromString` says: `The NSArray or NSDictionary represented by the object, or nil if an error occured.`

Comment: Print statuses and check what it is returning, NSArray or NSDictionary?

Comment: Can please show what exactly you are getting. Just print as NSLog(@"%@", [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]; );. No need to assign to any object.